# Is there a best practice in LUIS / any other MS service to identify relative clauses?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

i am setting up a chatbot and want to identify sentences that refere to a previous message. Like "that is nice!" or "is this still valid?".

I have thought about tagging pronouns like "that", "which" as entities in LUIS but this doesn't make too much sense for me. Is such a recognition even possible with LUIS or is an other MS service more suitable for that?

Example Dialog:

User: Are additional services included in offer A?

Bot: Our offer a covers free drinks and food.

User: Does that also cover free coffee...?

Comment: Could you please provide more context? A sample dialog would be helpful. I‘m having an idea but not sure if I got your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is such a recognition even possible with LUIS or is an other MS service more suitable for that?

No. But if you could create a model that would have a successful intent (reference previous response), then it should be fairly easy to get your bot to deal with the logic after getting that as topintent. Manage dialog, etc.